# Extract text from row of HTML table using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract the sunrise time (7:56AM) from the below HTML table using Python which I scraped using beautiful soup. It's the "text-right" of the second row, but I can't figure it out or find any resources guiding me, do I loop over the table to the second row?

First Light 7:20AM 
Sunrise     7:56AM

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-inverse table-tide">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>First Light</strong></td>
        <td class="text-right"> 7:20AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Sunrise</strong></td>
        <td class="text-right"> 7:56AM </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Excuse the dirty block of code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _but I can't figure it out or find any resources guiding me_ You can't find anything on parsing and manipulating HTML? Aren't you already using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could try to iterate over the td tag like that:

```
for td in soup.find_all('td', attrs={"class":"text-right"}):
    print(td.text)
```

output:

```
 7:20AM
 7:56AM
```